# Creating child paged in migrations files

Tags: django, migration, django-migrations, wagtail

I'm trying to create to index pages that are children of `home` page, some like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.7 on 2017-11-13 22:50
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def create_blogindexpage(apps, schema_editor):
    # Get models
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes.ContentType')
    BlogIndexPage = apps.get_model('blog.BlogIndexPage')
    HomePage = apps.get_model('home.HomePage')

    blogindexpage_content_type, __ = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(
        model='blogindexpage', app_label='blog')

    # Create a new blogindexpage
    blogindexpage = BlogIndexPage.objects.create(
        title="Blogs",
        draft_title="Blogs",
        slug='blogs',
        content_type=blogindexpage_content_type,
        path='000100010001',
        depth=3,
        numchild=0,
        url_path='/blogs/',
    )

    home_page = HomePage.objects.get(id=3)
    home_page.add_child(instance=blogindexpage)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('blog', '0001_initial'),
        ('home', '0002_create_homepage'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            create_blogindexpage,
        ),
    ]
```

This index of blogs have to be a child from the `home` page and this migration file depends of `home` `create_homepage` migration, but it give me this error:

```
File "./manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 193, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/Works/partnerlatam/blog.xprende/xprende/blog/migrations/0002_create_blogindexpage.py", line 30, in create_blogindexpage
    home_page.add_child(instance=blogindexpage)
AttributeError: 'HomePage' object has no attribute 'add_child'
```

I can't understand why i have this bug. I need to create this page and make them children from `home` page, how can i do that?

**UPDATE:**
I solved this question using this:

```
def create_blogindexpage(apps, schema_editor):
    from home.models import HomePage

    # Get models
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes.ContentType')
    BlogIndexPage = apps.get_model('blog.BlogIndexPage')

    blogindexpage_content_type, __ = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(
        model='blogindexpage', app_label='blog')

    home_page = HomePage.objects.get(id=3)
    home_page.add_child(
        instance=BlogIndexPage(
            title="Blogs",
            draft_title="Blogs",
            slug='blogs',
            content_type=blogindexpage_content_type,
            numchild=0,
            url_path='/blogs/',
        )
    )
```

It isn't the properly  way but, if you can see my comments, i don't know how can i do it using `move` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving Wagtail pages in a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594187/moving-wagtail-pages-in-a-migration)

Comment: Similar but not, when i try to do it in the sell i get problems because these page exiting already in the tree but the aren't showed in the admin like `home` page's children.

Comment: I did tried moving both pages in the shell: In [8]: personindexpage.move(homepage,'last-child')

In [9]: blogindexpage = BlogIndexPage.objects.get(id=4)

In [10]: blogindexpage.move(homepage,'first-child')

But still i can't see them in the admin.

Comment: It might  be worth checking for tree problems, you can use the 'find_problems' method on your pages, ideally run it in shell on your root page (which should be pk=1). http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.find_problems